# Geofencing has a wrong behavior when entering and exiting from tracked regions

Tags: react-native, location, expo

I'm new using [Geofencing API](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/location.md#geofencing)

#### Problem

The problem occurs when I'm tracking geofencing regions and I enter and exit from one of them.

Start tracking geofencing regions

```
Location.startGeofencingAsync(taskName, regions)
```

Let's call the regions A (first) and B(the 2nd one). I'll replace the regions ID to a better understanding

**A -> 5dc96f5012892600119df8b8**

**B -> 5dc96f8d12892600119df8b9**

```
[
  {
      "identifier": "A",
      "latitude": 42.66948587788525,
      "longitude": 23.351275976747278,
      "notifyOnEnter": true,
      "notifyOnExit": true,
      "radius": 245,
    },
    {
      "identifier": "B",
      "latitude": 42.698528709750214,
      "longitude": 23.30798713490367,
      "notifyOnEnter": true,
      "notifyOnExit": true,
      "radius": 431,
    },
  ],
```

On the main app file there is a task running in the background

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

TaskManager.defineTask(MY_TASK_NAME, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
  } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
  }
});
```

#### Actual Behavior

Entering to region A console output is

```
You've entered region: Object {
  "identifier": "5dc96f5012892600119df8b8",
  "latitude": 42.66948587788525,
  "longitude": 23.351275976747278,
  "radius": 245,
  "state": 1,
}

Perfect output.
```

Now, exiting from region A end entering to region B console output is

```
You've entered region: Object {
  "identifier": "B",
  "latitude": 42.698528709750214,
  "longitude": 23.30798713490367,
  "radius": 431,
  "state": 1,
}

You've entered region: Object {
  "identifier": "B",
  "latitude": 42.698528709750214,
  "longitude": 23.30798713490367,
  "radius": 431,
  "state": 1,
}

You've left region: Object {
  "identifier": "A",
  "latitude": 42.66948587788525,
  "longitude": 23.351275976747278,
  "radius": 245,
  "state": 2,
}
```

I got two entering events to region B. Why is this happening?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

#### Environment

```
Pixel Android 10, on an android emulator

"expo": "33.0.7"
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
"expo-location": "7.0.0",
"expo-task-manager": "7.0.0",

Expo CLI 3.4.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.19.1 - C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
```